# How to add an NSArray as a NSMutableDictionary key for a NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, plist

I tried doing the following:

```
NSMutableArray *myArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myDict objectForKey:@"myKey"]];
[myArr addObject:@"New string xxx"];
[myDict setObject:myArr forKey:@"myKey"];
// Write to file (done successfully)
```

As you can see, I get an array which is stored on a plist with the key `@"myKey"`, add some objects to it and want to re-record it on the plist, with some extra values of course.

Problem is, the following happens on my plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>myKey</key>
        <array>
                <string>First entry on the plist</string>

                <array>
                    <string>First entry on the plist</string>
                    <string>New string xxx</string>
                </array>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The desired output is, of course:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
            <key>myKey</key>
            <array>
                    <string>First entry on the plist</string>
                    <string>New string xxx</string>
            </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: Two things: 1. an NSLog(@"myDict: %@", myDict); will display the dictionary without a need to write it. 2. Think carefully about exactly every statement is doing.  Break down compound statements into multiple statements that do one thing each.  An example is the first statement that does two things, access the content of  dictionary and initials an array.  This will make it much easier to understand what is happening or make it clear that that a statement is not understood.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem with the code posted. Is `myDict` in expected state before the code you posted is executed and in unexpected state after it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `[myDict removeObjectForKey:@"myKey"]` before setting it again?

Answer (score 0):

its working fine

```
NSMutableArray *myArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myDict objectForKey:@"myKey"]];
[myArr addObject:@"New string xxx"];
[myDict setObject:myArr forKey:@"myKey"];
[myDict writeToFile:@"/path/p.text" atomically:NO];
[myArr addObject:@"new object"];
[myDict setObject:myArr forKey:@"myKey"];
[myDict writeToFile:@"/path/p.text" atomically:NO];
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>myKey</key>
    <array>
        <string>New string xxx</string>
        <string>new object</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```